# Video conferencing using opentok

Tags: video-conferencing, opentok

How can i add clients to a video chat using their email id in opentok.I have tried opentok using javascript api,but i can only see my face in the browser.Is there any way to add clients using facebook account?

Answer (score 2):

No. To see video streams from other people they would need to:
1. be connected to to same session Id as you are
2. be publishing to the session
TO add clients to a video chat, I would simply send them a link (via email or fb messages) to your site with a specific sessionId, and on page load the site will connect to the session, publish video, and subscribe to other video streams.

Here's [an awesome quick tutorial](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/getting-started-with-opentok-from-0-to-simple-group-video-chat/) to get you started

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tokbox.com and under the widgets title, click the add to your site link.
Choose the Basic Embed option, enter a valid e-mail address and then click the Get code link. 
Copy the code provided by Tokbox to your clipboard.
You can paste your code into any page or widget that accepts HTML code. From within Content Editing mode

Adding HTML To A Sidebar.

Once you've added your embed code, this is it how it will appear in the content editor.
After embedding your Tokbox code you may be prompted to enable access to your camera and microphone. If that occurs, click allow. You will then see the Tokbox video chat widget appearing within your site.
And that's it! You're ready to start a video chat. Once a video chat has been initiated, you can moderate your session by ticking the I'm a moderator prompt in your chat window and typing in the secret code you received from Tokbox in your e-mail when signing up.
More about OpenTok:
[Mobile chat app development](http://tecsynt.com/blog/mobile_chat_app_development/)
[Creating an iPhone video chat app using Parse and Opentok](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/22)